# How to find coordinates of an abstract vector relative to a basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let's say I have a degree 3 homogeneous polynomial over variables $x0, x1, x2.$  There are then 10 distinct monic monomials, forming a basis of the vector space of polynomials of degree 3.  If I have another polynomial of degree 3 in $x0, x1, x2$, how can I find out the coordinates of the expansion, returning a list according to some chosen ordering of the monomials?  So the desired output would be a list of 10 numbers.  For example, let's say I want the ordering $x0^3, x0^2x1, x0^2x2, x0x1^2, x0x1x2, x0x2^2, x1^3, x1^2x2, x1x2^2, x2^3$ and I want the output corresponding to the polynomial $(x0+x1)^2x0$.  Then I want the output to be the array {1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}.

The degree 3 was an arbitrary choice, and therefore as was the 10-dimensionality.  So the method needs to at least work for fixed degree at a time, if not necessarily so that I can put in a degree at the very beginning for it to always work.  Also, eventually I will want to take an array of polynomials and want to generate a list of lists of coefficients, so hopefully the method suggested will be amenable to this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want [`PolynomialReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PolynomialReduce.html)

```
base = {x^3, x^2 y, x^2 z, x y^2, xyz, x z^2, y^3, y^2 z, y z^2, z^3}
PolynomialReduce[(x + y)^2 x, base, {x, y}]
(* {{1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 0} *)
```

You might also find [`GroebnerBasis`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GroebnerBasis.html) interesting, [scholarpedia](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Groebner_basis) has a nice overview.

Comment: +1. Thanks for that reference on Groebner basis too, I've always wanted to learn about it.